# Custom Error Page For [dot] in URL in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, custom-error-pages

In my codeigniter project, I have set error page for 404 page not found. It works fine but when I hit url with dot[.] at last or between url, It shows apache's 404 page not found message instead of my error page.

plz help me if anyone can...

Comment: I have solved out this problem.....by adding [^/.]* rewrite condition in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Make a new file called `.htaccess` in project root folder if not exists and add below code in it with 404 url.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
```